# Call Delphi CLASS exported in DLL from C++ code

Tags: c++, class, delphi, dll, interface

i have a problem to use delphi class from C++ code.  delphi dll demo that export a function that return an object.
my delphi Dll code is as follow:

```
 library DelphiTest; 
 // uses part....
 type
 IMyObject = interface
   procedure DoThis( n: Integer );
   function DoThat : PWideChar;
end;
TMyObject = class(TInterfacedObject,IMyObject)
   procedure DoThis( n: Integer );
   function DoThat: PChar;
end;
// TMyObject implementation go here ...
procedure TMyObject.DoThis( n: Integer );
begin
 showmessage('you are calling the DoThis methode with '+intToStr(n) +'parameter');
end;

function TMyObject.DoThat: PChar;
begin
  showmessage('you are calling the DoThat function');
  Result := Pchar('Hello im Dothat');
end;
```

// exporting DLL function :

```
function CreateMyObject : IMyObject; stdcall;export;
var
 txt : TextFile;
begin
  AssignFile(txt,'C:\log.log');
  Reset(txt);
  Writeln(txt,'hello');
  Result := TMyObject.Create;
end;

exports  CreateMyObject;
```

in my C++ project i declared the IMyObject interface as follow :

```
   class IMyObject
    {
       public:
         IMyObject();
         virtual ~IMyObject();
         virtual void DoThis(int n) = 0;
         virtual char* DoThat() = 0;
    };
```

and my main function as follow :

```
typedef  IMyObject* (__stdcall *CreateFn)();

int main()
{
HMODULE hLib;
hLib = LoadLibrary(L"DelphiTest.dll");

assert(hLib != NULL); // pass !!
CreateFn pfnCreate;
pfnCreate = (CreateFn)GetProcAddress((HINSTANCE)hLib, "CreateMyObject");

if (pfnCreate == NULL)
{
    DWORD errc = GetLastError();
    printf("%u\n", errc); // it gets error 127

}
else{
    printf("success load\n");
}
   IMyObject*  objptr = pfnCreate();
   objptr->DoThis(5);
   FreeLibrary(hLib);
   int in;
   scanf_s("%i", &in);
   return 0;
 }
```

with this example i got an error at run time when i try to access the exported function. the errors is at line :
`IMyObject*  objptr = pfnCreate();`

can you tell me what is wrong about my example.
and if possible any working example to access Delphi class (in DLL) from C++ code.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is calling convention of the methods. The Delphi interface uses `register` which is a Delphi specific calling convention. Use `stdcall`, for example, for the methods of the interface.

The next problem is in the C++. Your C++ interface must derive from `IUnknown`. Further, it should not declare a constructor or destructor.

Beyond that your Delphi code exports `PWideChar` which does not map to `char*`. It maps to `wchar_t*`.

Looking further ahead, returning a `PChar` works fine here because your implementation returns a literal. But more serious code will want to use a dynamically allocated string presumably and at that point your design is flawed.

Do note that you need to be an elevate administrator to create a file at the root of the system drive. So that's yet another potential failure point.

I expect there are other mistakes, but that's all I've found so far.

Comment: i changed as follow  in my C++ interface :  `#include<Unknwn.h>
class IMyObject : IUnknown
{
public:
 virtual void DoThis(int n) = 0;
 virtual char* DoThat() = 0;`  and in my Delphi interface as follow :  ` procedure DoThis( n: Integer );  stdcall;
    function DoThat : PWideChar;  stdcall;`   but i stil get the same error.

Comment: Well, you've ignored half of my answer.

Comment: @Remy No. Read the interface declaration. It says `PWideChar`.

Comment: @Nabil: don't forget to call `objptr->Release()` before calling `FreeLibrary()`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Yes, you are right, I only saw the `PChar` on the implementation, not the `PWideChar` on the interface declaration.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan , i have applied all what you have recommanded. but did not mentioned that in the comment.  i also added the `objptr->Release()` and i still get the error. maybe it helps to : i compile my DLL using Delphi XE6 , and my C++ test project using VS2013.

Comment: You haven't told us what the error is yet. Try removing all the Delphi code inside the functions. Then use a debugger. Have you ever done any debugging?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: i tried to remove all code from functions "Dothis" and "Dothat". but i still get the error.     yes im runing in debug mode. this is screenshot of ![my debug window with the error] (https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2BsvFgoBlF3RXJ1TE9XcFd3OHM)