# How to use C++ to call Delphi class through dll

Tags: c++, delphi, dll

- My question is the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35508818/call-delphi-class-exported-in-dll-from-c-code):
- But the answer does not really answer the most important question:
  **Why is an error reported when calling the class**
- The obvious answerer did not explain abovequestion

I try dll made by C++ (Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.2), and used by C++, this is ok(include class)
I try dll made by delphi (Delphi XE and Delphi 10.2), and used by delphi, this is ok (include class)
I try dll made by delphi, and used by C++, if there is no class, this is ok
but when i use C++ to call Delphi class, this is go error
as follos is my code:

- **dll code** `HYDataSet.dpr`

```
library HYDataSet;

uses
  SysUtils,
  Classes,
  uHyDataSet in 'uHyDataSet.pas';
var
  GlobalHyDataSet: IHyDataSet;
//test integer
Function TestAdd(p1, p2 : Integer):Integer;stdcall;
begin
  Result:=p1+p2;
end;

//test Double
Function TestDouble(p1, p2 : Double):Double;stdcall;
begin
  Result:=p1+p2;
end;

//Boolean
Function TestBoolean(p1, p2 : Boolean):Boolean;stdcall;
begin
  Result:=p1 and p2;
end;

//string
procedure ShowString(s1, s2, pOut: PAnsiChar); stdcall;
var
  strRes:String;
  Ps:PAnsichar;
begin
  strRes := 'this is from delphi s1：'+ StrPas(s1) + ' s2:' + StrPas(s2);
  StrPCopy(pOut, strRes);
end;

//class
function getClass(): IHyDataSet; stdcall;
begin
  if GlobalHyDataSet = nil then
    GlobalHyDataSet := THyDataSet.Create;
  Result := GlobalHyDataSet;
end;

function freeClass(): Boolean; stdcall;
begin
  Result := False;
  if GlobalHyDataSet <> nil then
  begin
    GlobalHyDataSet := nil;
    Result := True;
  end;
end;

{$R *.res}
exports
  TestAdd,
  ShowString,
  TestDouble,
  TestBoolean,
  getClass,
  freeClass;
begin
end.
```

- **dll code** `uHyDataSet.pas`

```
unit uHyDataSet;

interface
type


  IHyDataSet = interface
    function testAdd(a, b: Integer): Integer;stdcall;
  end;

  THyDataSet = class(TInterfacedObject, IHyDataSet)
  private
     FName: string;
  public
     function testAdd(a, b: Integer): Integer;stdcall;
  end;
implementation

function THyDataSet.testAdd(a, b: Integer): Integer;stdcall;
begin
  Result := a + b;
end;

end.
```

- **C++ code** `main.cpp`

```
#include <tchar.h>  
using namespace std;

class HyDataSet: IUnknown {
public:
    virtual int __stdcall testAdd(int a, int b) = 0;
};

void DynamicUse()
{
    HMODULE module = LoadLibrary(_T("HYDataSet.dll"));
    if (module == NULL)
    {
        printf("load DLL fail\n");
        return;
    }
    typedef int(__stdcall *TestAdd)(int, int); 
    typedef double(__stdcall *TestDouble)(double, double); 
    typedef bool(__stdcall *TestBoolean)(bool, bool); 
    typedef void(__stdcall *ShowString)(const char*, const char*, char*); 
    typedef HyDataSet *(__stdcall* getClass)();
    using pExport = HyDataSet * (*)(void);
    TestAdd add;

    add = (TestAdd)GetProcAddress(module, "TestAdd");
    int sum = add(100, 200);
    cout<< sum <<endl;

    TestDouble add2;
    add2 = (TestDouble)GetProcAddress(module, "TestDouble");
    double sum2 = add2(100.1, 200.2);
    cout << sum2 << endl;

    TestBoolean boo;
    boo = (TestBoolean)GetProcAddress(module, "TestBoolean");
    boolean result = boo(true, false);
    cout << result << endl;

    ShowString ss;
    ss = (ShowString)GetProcAddress(module, "ShowString");
    char* pBuf = new char[512];
    memset(pBuf, 0, 512);
    ss("2018 delphi", "中文测试", pBuf);
    cout << pBuf << endl;
    delete[] pBuf;

    getClass gc;
    gc = (getClass)GetProcAddress(module, "getClass");
    //pExport gc = (pExport)GetProcAddress(module, "getClass");
    HyDataSet * hyDataSet = gc();
    int sum3 = hyDataSet->testAdd(20, 10);
    cout << sum3 << endl;
}
```

**it will be error at :**

```
HyDataSet * hyDataSet = gc();
```

i think maybe it should be a pointer, so i change the code in `HYDataSet.dpr`

```
function getClass(): IHyDataSet; stdcall;
begin
  if GlobalHyDataSet = nil then
    GlobalHyDataSet := THyDataSet.Create;
  Result := GlobalHyDataSet;
end;
```

change to

```
function getClass(): Pointer; stdcall;
begin
  if GlobalHyDataSet = nil then
    GlobalHyDataSet := THyDataSet.Create;
  Result := @GlobalHyDataSet;
end;
```

**it will be error at :**

```
int sum3 = hyDataSet->testAdd(20, 10);
```

i don't know the class pointer's address is right or not...
can you tell me what is wrong about my example. and if possible any working example to access Delphi class (in DLL) from C++ code.
Please don’t fail to answer the core question like the previous responder.tks~

Comment: There is no standard convention for invoking methods of classes. Internal layouts of classes in Delphi, gcc, msvc and other C++ compilers like Intel C++ are different. The only reliable ways to call methods of other's compiler class are 1) writing wrappers with the DLL's compiler with plain functions or COM interfaces 2) reverse engineering a DLL and writing calling code on internal assembly by yourself.

Comment: @Doj Tks, I know that....

Comment: What exactly about the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35509013/65863) was unclear to you? It correctly explains the issues and how to solve them. There are several mismatches between the Delphi code and C++ code, all of which contribute to why the crash occurs. The code shown above suffers from a class layout mismatch, and a calling convention mismatch. The declarations of `HyDataSet` itself and its `testAdd()` method on the C++ side do not match the declarations of `IHyDataSet` and `testAdd()` on the Delphi side.

Comment: @RemyLebeau ,I modified all the things he mentioned based on other answer, such as stdcall Char, and in function it work well.but class error. Why is the class reporting errors is what I and another question want to ask, i konw the delphi'class if do not match C++ class, Is there any solution?
Or is there any way to make them consistent?

Comment: @Para “*I modified all of the things he mentioned*” - then please update your question here to show your latest code. Because the code currently shown does not take into account the things he said to change.

Comment: Which C++ compiler are you using? Which Delphi version are you using?

Comment: @RemyLebeau sorry,I don't know what else i missed, he mentioned 1.stdcall2.IUnknown3.char all above i modified

Comment: @fpiette delphi xe delphi10.2 is the same result. and c++ i used msvc

Comment: @Para on the C++ side, `HyDataSet` should be declared as `class HyDataSet : public IUnknown { virtual int __stdcall testAdd(int a, int b) = 0; };` And on the Delphi side, `IHyDataSet` should be declared as `IHyDataSet = interface function testAdd(a, b: Integer): Integer; stdcall; end;` IF AND ONLY IF the C++ compiler used is C++Builder then you can drop the `stdcall` on the Delphi side, and use `__fastcall` instead of `__stdcall` on the C++ side. But since you are using MSVC instead, you need a calling convention that both Delphi and C++ support.

Comment: Thanks for Delphi version. You forgot to mention which MSVC version you used. Please edit your question to add ALL the information you gave in the comments so that next reader has not to read everything to fully understand. The question should be self contained.

Comment: @Para also, making `getClass()` return an untyped pointer is just wrong, as it would bypass `IUnknown`’s normal reference counting semantics. Not that it matters, since that version of `getClass()` is also returning the wrong pointer anyway, which will also cause problems. `@GlobalHyDataSet` is the address of the `GlobalHyDataSet` variable itself, not the address of the `THyDataSet` object that it points to.

Comment: @fpiette Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.2, The reason I don’t show that is because I don’t think it was caused by version's problem, thk~

Comment: @RemyLebeau, tks again, i change the code about stdcall, but it do not work(not pointer version).... about the pointer: why GlobalHyDataSet's pointer is not the address of the THyDataSet object?The memory of exe and dll can be read from each other, I'm a newer In cpp,mybe Can you help write a simple demo that can be used? sincerely gratitude

Comment: @Para if you don’t understand the difference being the address of a pointer variable versus the address the pointer is pointing at, then I suggest you do some more research on how pointers work. In any case, another possibility is the Delphi compiler *may* be returning the `IHyDataSet` pointer as a hidden `var` parameter instead of in the `EAX` CPU register, like C++ would normally do. So that is another possible mismatch between compilers. So on the C++side, try using `typedef void (__stdcall* getClass)(IHyDataSet*&)` and then call it like `HyDataSet *hyDataSet = nullptr; gc(hyDataSet);`

Comment: @Para You are also missing a call to `hyDataSet->Release()` when you are done using the object, otherwise it will be leaked.

Comment: http://www.rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-dlls.html